# Matching multiple times a regular expression on .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I come again for your help. I have right now a huge .htaccess file that we use to prettify our URLs.  This is usually pretty straightforward, but I got on an issue now that I don't know how to solve. Were it PCRE I knew I could simply do a foreach to process this, but in .htaccess I do not know how to proceed.

My URl can have a set of page ids regarding separated blocks on the page, this is the code I'm using to match it `(?:/((?:glc|gli[0-9]+)?page)/([0-9]+))` and I add it to my [L,QSA] rule as `$1=$2` (the expression is much more complex than it, I'm simply getting the relevant part).

Normally a pageid may appear or not on an url, and on those cases I simply add  a `?` at the end of it, but on this particular URL I may have up to 28 of these. I could add a `*` or a more specific `{0,28}` to the match pattern, but I have no idea how to reference each pair on return part.

Briefly, I want to convert:

```
/page/10/glcpage/1/gli123/9 => page=10&glcpage=1&gli123page=9
/page/5 => page=5
```

etc

**Anyone got any idea?**

For those sadistic enough this is the full regexp. The pageid=$4 is the *normal* code for grabbing the page when there is only 1 possibility on the url. That's what I'm trying to change.

```
^modsystem/([0-9]+)(?:/(?!(?:glc|gli[0-9]+)?page/[0-9]+|comment/[0-9]+|module/[0-9]+)([^/]+))?(?:/module/([0-9]+))?(?:/((?:glc|gli[0-9]+)?page)/([0-9]+))*(?:/comment/([0-9]+))?

/modsystem.php?action=showall&modsystemid=$1&seoslug=$2&moduleid=$3&pageid=$4&commentid=$5

[L,QSA]
```

EDIT: Fixing some parenthesis that got wrongly copied

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to test individually for each possible pageid.  There's no way to loop through the matches or handle a variable number of matches.